# Field 'id' expected a number but got

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I try to build follow system in Django, it showed Field 'id' expected a number but got ''. how can i get the pk of the current profile user which I vested.

This my view

```
def follow_unfollow_profile(request, **kwargs):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        my_account = Account.objects.get(username=request.user)
        pk = request.POST.get('account_pk')
        obj = Account.objects.get(pk=pk)

        if obj.username in my_account.following.all():
            my_account.following.remove(obj.username)
        else:
            my_account.following.add(obj.username)
        return redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

This is the urls

```
path('<int:user_id>/', account_view, name="view"),
path('follow/', follow_unfollow_profile, name='follow-unfollow-view'),
```

The form Which I try to get the object pk

```
<form action="{% url 'account:follow-unfollow-view'%}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="account_pk" value={{account.pk}}>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Follow</button>
</form>
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Comment: maybe first check what you have in `form` in HTML in browser (ie. Ctrl+U) and later check what you get in `request.POST` in `django` - maybe you send empty string to template and browser gets `value=""` and later you get empty string in django. Where is function which generate this form?

Answer (score 2):

First, you have to change the line, unless your username is a primary key:

```
 my_account = Account.objects.get(username=request.user)
```

To:

```
my_account = Account.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
```

In this line you try put string (username) to manytomany field:

```
    if obj.username in my_account.following.all():
        my_account.following.remove(obj.username)
    else:
        my_account.following.add(obj.username)
```

Change it to:

```
    if obj in my_account.following.all():
        my_account.following.remove(obj)
    else:
        my_account.following.add(obj)
```

This isn't good practice:

```
redirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))
```

Answer (score -1):

*Does it happen when you **run** server or **migrate** or **migration*** ?

if it is happened at that time.

1. First real possible solution is that you should delete SQL then reload sql file (For example I use --> db.sqlite3 for saving information into database) then when you enter file that contains in **INSTALLED_APPS**, you must see migration folder then you need to enter inside of it afterwards as you can see the file which is named ***init*** , delete all files there except ***init*** (don't delete it because of package file)
2. Second solution quite complex way is that you can work with database and change one by one through using your intelligence in database.